# Python: Remove scientific notaion when calling DictWriter

Tags: python, csv

I've looked into the current responses but couldn't find my specific case....
I have a dictionnary of floats that have big values, and I want to dump the entire dict into a csv file, without any scientific notations.
example :

```
import csv
csv_file = r"D:/temp/test.csv"
long_num_dict = {
  'number1': [123456789984987954654687654.20, 19879842619984987954654687654.20],
  'number2': [515456789984987954654687654.20, 19879842619989875465654687654.20]
}
with open(csv_file, 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, long_num_dict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(long_num_dict)
```

my csv looks like this :

```
number1,number2

"[1.2345678998498796e+26, 1.987984261998499e+28]","[5.154567899849879e+26, 1.9879842619989875e+28]"
```

How do I remove the scientific notations ? I'm losing precision here... And please be advised that in my case, I got big dictionnaries :)

Thanks all

Comment: Do you really want to have a csv file with 2 string representations of lists?

Comment: This doesn't make sense, why are you doing `w.writerow(long_num_dict)`? you are trying to put lists in each individual row?

Comment: You can use the `decimal` module with this.

Comment: mmh, yeah true I did not think much further, I just need a function that stores my data in a file, and another that reads it later on. looking into stackoverflow, I came across some descriptions that uses csvs like this. But indeed this might not have been the smartest way, I didn't want to use pickle or some other binary data.

Comment: but still, is there no way to force my data to have no scientifc notation ?

Comment: it's mainly that my dictionnary has different sizes of tabs, so maybe there is another better way to store data into a csv ?

Comment: yes, you need to format the string itself, and you need to iterate over the values such that each row is an actual row